# Octave: How can I vectorize this function?

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization, octave

Can these for-loops of this function be vectorized?

```
function [sta]=bootstrap(data,N,p)
rand('state', sum(100*clock));
n=length(data);
n1=round(prctile(1:n,(100-p)/2));
n2=round(prctile(1:n,p/2+50));
for i=1:N
    choose=round(((n-1)*rand(1,n))+1);
    for j=n1:n2
        sample(j-n1+1,1)=data(choose(j));
    end
sta(i)=mean(sample);
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want help improving your code it's always advisable to describe in a few words what you are trying to archive, what is the desired output, then a complete runnable script how you've tried it so far. Without this you expect that someone reads your code, then figures out what problem you might want to solve and then to provide a better alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, try to replace your loop with the code below:

`choose=round(((n-1)*rand(N,n))+1);
sample(:,(n1:n2)-n1+1,1)=data(choose(:,n1:n2));
sta=mean(sample');`

The point is you should replace `i` and `j` with the vectors you assigned for them in `for` block.